# MapView annotation View without Clicking

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview, mapkit

In my application show Multiple Annotation between two city but when we move one Annotation to other (with map region set on next previous Button) how to show Annotation detail automatic without clicking on it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can test with the title of the annotation, if it mach, you can use

```
selectAnnotation: animated:
```

to show the Annotation ( you can subclass MKAnnotation and add an id for test instead title ):

```
for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in mapView.annotations) 
{   
    if( [annotation.title isEqualToString:title]) [mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: hey but how we compare the title ??? In this  [annotation.title isEqualToString:title] title how we get

Comment: you know what point you have to show,right? for example if you have a tableView, when you click on a row you have the index of "the wanted pointName " in an array so you get that pointName and you compare it ( in my case i named it title ).
Im note sure to understand what is the scenario befor showing the point.